# Minimize (xy-1)^2 + x^2

Tags: optimization

I am practicing for my final exam and I came across this exercise online.
Yet, I have no clue how to solve it.

> min (xy-1)^2 + x^2

I figured the four step method would be a good idea.
I got stuck on how to prove Weierstrass.
Also, the solution I got with the First Order Necessary Conditions is the answer 1. From the plot, however, I can see there should be multiple solutions to this exercise.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=(xy-1)^2+x^2$. Then $f(x,y) \ge 0$ for all $(x,y)$.

For $x \ne 0$: $f(x, \frac{1}{x})=x^2 \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.

Hence $ \inf \{f(x,y):(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\}=0$, but there is no $(a,b)$ such that $f(a,b)=0$.

Conclusion: $ \min \{f(x,y):(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\}$ does not exist !

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But how can I prove that the function is not coercive?